# How to copy all row from source table to another using Eloquent on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have small Laravel project working on copying rows from source table to another target table. There's example of source table.

```
Source table
id   branch   productname   productprice
1      0        productA        5
2      0        productB        10
```

Then, Copy all rows form source table to target table with new branch value = 1. So, the target table table will be.

```
Target table
id   branch   productname   productprice
1      1        productA        5
2      1        productB        10
```

And also. If I add more branch, let the branch value = 2. So, the target table will be appended.

```
Target table
id   branch   productname   productprice
1      1        productA        5
2      1        productB        10
3      2        productA        5
4      2        productB        10
```

I can do by using loop thought, but I'm not is it the correct way. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Tasks? @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: maybe $oldTable = Product::where()->get()->toArray(); /  $copy = $oldTable->replicate()  / then DB::table('newtable')->insert($copy); not 100% sure

Comment: Dear Ahmed Aboud, Thanks but not try yet because of not only copy rows but I have to edit filed branch to new value before insert to new table.

Comment: Dear Ahmed Aboud, It's work great. Thank you very much.